# react router public path url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

From all tutorial I read they use and setting react-router with "/" for their route path and http://mysite.or/ as their domain. what if I want "http://mysite.or/something" for my base path (home). Do I just need to change(add) the "/" on react-router to become "/something". or is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you use path as "/something" for parent Route component then /something will be the base path. But it would be better to use "/" at the parent and you create a subparent Route component with base path "/something"

```
<Route path="/">
  <Route path="/something">
     //Put routes that needs base path as /something/...
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `basename` is the proper way to go about this now.

I like to use `PUBLIC_URL` for this so I can change it for different deployment scenarios.

```jsx
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
```

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

> basename: string
>
> The base URL for all locations. If your app is served from a sub-directory on your server, you’ll want to set this to the sub-directory. A properly formatted basename should have a leading slash, but no trailing slash.

```jsx
<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar">
    <Link to="/today"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/today">
    <Link to="/tomorrow"/> // renders <a href="/calendar/tomorrow">
    ...
</BrowserRouter>
```